# Can I route a firebase request to a GCP cloud function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

Is there someway I can route a request directly to a GCP cloud function?

For example the following:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/",
        "function": "example"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However the above seems to point to a firebase function rather than a GCP cloud function. Even though the GCP function appears as a 'function' in Firebase Functions?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that is exactly the correct syntax however `/` did not seem to work. When I changed it to `/test` it then worked correctly...

This is because `/` would resolve to the default `public/index.html` file instead.